# Что такое невпритям

Tags: этимология, семантика

Было бы интересно послушать мнение форумчан о смысле и происхождении слова *невпритям*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Невпритям  (не в примету, невдомек) - от глагола "тямить" - видеть, слышать, разуметь, помнить.

http://slovari.yandex.ru/~книги/Толковый%20словарь%20Даля/ТЯМИТЬ/

ТЯМИТЬ что, южн. зап. тамб. пск. тямлить, вор. (темя?) знать, разуметь, смыслить или понимать; уметь, мороковать; || видеть, слышать, постигать чувствами; || помнить.

Не тямишь, так не берись. Он тямит по-русски, тямит грамоту. Ему, что ни говори, ничего не тямит. Не тямлю я издалеча, глаза плохи.

Тямиться кому, безличн. помниться, думаться, видеться, казаться, мниться. Тямится, будто это было до Петровок? || Помнится.

Тям м. тямка ж. пониманье, постиженье, распознаванье; разум, рассудок, смысл, сметка, догадка: память. У него тямки нет, не берет в тям, не взял в тямку. Не в тямку мне, не дослышал; ||

не в память, не помню. А мне-то и не в тям, чего он хочет! Обиняки не в тямку нам. Ему тямку или все тямки отбили, поглупел, обезумел, одурел. Тямкий человек, понятливый, сметливый, догадливый; способный, смышленый; памятливый.

Answer (score 3):

Как всегда, начнем словарный поиск.

> ТЯМА
> Не хватает тямы кому. Дон. Шутл.-ирон. О человеке, который не может чего-л. понять, сообразить. СДГ 3, 167.
>
> Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007.

Украинский источник :

> ТЯМА
> -и, ж., розм.
> Здатність осмислювати що-не-будь; кмітливість, тямущість; розум. || рідко. Свідомість.
> ••
>
> Без тя/ми — а) нічого не усвідомлюючи, з потьмареною свідомістю; б) без пам'яті; в непритомному стані. Дійти до тями.
>
> Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.

Итак, тяма - "понятливость". Интересная ссылка :
http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=96461
("Тямы нет - считай, калека...")

Кроме *тямы*, есть много других однокоренных с ним слов. Почитаем словарь Преображенского (1914) :

> *Тямить (тямлю, тямишь)* - замечать, понимать, запоминать...
> *Тямиться* - помниться
> *Притямить* - приметить
> *Тямкий* - сметливый, способный замечать... 
> *Растемяшить* - отчетливо понять; переходн. - растолковать, объяснить...
> *Втемяшить* - втолковать...
> Украин. *тЯмити* - смыслить, понимать...
> *тЯма* - понимание, сметка...
> *у тямкИ бути* - врезаться в память...
> *тямовитый* - понятливый...
> Белорусск. *цямiць* - помнить...
> *цямно* - памятно...
> *на цямкi* - на память {по памяти}
> Литов. *temytis* - держать в памяти {+ греческие параллели}

Имеет ли отношение к *тяме* - темя, темячко? А память?? Пока что немного непонятно,*невпритям*) Следует продолжить поиск...

Answer (score 2):

Как **предположение**.

На Украине употребляется слово **"тЯма"**, что можно перевести приблизительно как "соображение". И слово **"непритомний"** [нэпрытОмный] - без сознания.

Возможно, "невпритям" как-то с этими словами связано?

"Тямити" в чём-либо -- это значит соображать в чём-либо, т.е. разбираться в каком-то деле.
"Без тями" - без сознания, либо потеряв самообладание, самоконтроль. 
"ТямУщий" - сообразительный, разбирающийся в чём-либо.

Могу предположить, что **"невпритям"** значит **"не соображу"**.

Comment: Nikolja,   
*НЕВПРИТЯМ нареч. калужск. невдомек, не в примету. “Не видал ли тут теленка?” Нет, невпритям что-то.*  

(С)Даль

Других источников или использования не наблюдается.
Так что это никак не украинское.

Comment: >Так что это никак не украинское. 

Да, согласен. Такого слова как "невпритям" на Украине лично мне слышать не приходилось.

Я предположил, что возможно есть какая-то старинная связь. Старорусская или старославянская. Хотя, конечно, не факт, что есть.

Comment: Всё-таки есть связь. Уважаемая @София ниже утверждает, что:

>Невпритям (не в примету, невдомек) - от глагола "тямить" - видеть, слышать, разуметь, помнить.

Comment: Ну уж если София утверждает ))))

Answer (score 2):

по -белорусски ЦЯМІЦЬ - соображать, смекать

Answer (score 2):

Забыли  про  Втемяшить--вбить в голову, убедить, заставить думать.

вопреки Васмеру, который не врубился, что есть еще "темя", по которому  подзатыльники при учебе. А еще есть рефлекс такой, сильно задумавшись именно темя и чешут, видимо помогает. Нынче говорят, репу чесать.

темяшить темя́шить темя́сить "бить кулаком", втемя́шиться (напр. у Мельникова), укр. тем᾽яжи́ти "давить", польск. ciemiężyć "притеснять, подавлять". Сближается с предыдущим и с тя́мить (см.) (Мi. ЕW 356; Брюкнер 62). Неясно. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

оттуда  и слово "тема" - в смысле предмета размышлений, опять вопреки Васмеру